# How do I get symmetry in this string concatentation?

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

This is supposed to be a fairly simple question, but this somehow tripped me up. Some kind of symbols, e.g: <<>>, [] and a word is passed as a parameter into the function 'encase_word', and I have to somehow get the word inside the symbols.

Test cases and expected output:

```
print(encase_word('<<>>', 'Hello')) #Expected output: <<hello>>
print(encase_word('[]', 'Hello')) #Expected output: [Hello]
```

Full code

```
def main():
    print(encase_word('<<>>', 'Hello')) #Expected output: <<hello>>
    print(encase_word('[]', 'Hello')) #Expected output: [Hello]

def encase_word(out, word):
    get_1 = out[:2]
    get_2 = out[2:]
    make_word = get_1 + word + get_2
    return make_word

main()
```

However, I'm struggling to get the word inside the square brackets where I would get []Hello instead of [Hello].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using division to get the length of the string divided by 2 and get the first n then add the word the add the last n:

```
def main():
    print(encase_word('<<>>', 'Hello')) #<<hello>>
    print(encase_word('[]', 'Hello')) #[Hello]

def encase_word(out, word):
    return out[:len(out)//2] + word + out[len(out)//2:]

main()
```

Output:

```
<<Hello>>
[Hello]
```